# Selection control returning array with undefined values in azure maps

Tags: azure-maps

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Selection control - Azure Maps Web SDK Samples</title>

    

    <!-- Add references to the Azure Maps Map control JavaScript and CSS files. -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.css"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <script src="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Add references to the Azure Maps Map Drawing Tools JavaScript and CSS files. -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/drawing/0/atlas-drawing.min.css"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <script src="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/drawing/0/atlas-drawing.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Add references to the Azure Maps Selection Control module JavaScript and CSS files. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./selectionControl.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="./selectionControl.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map, datasource;

      //GeoJSON feed that contains the data we want to map.
      var geojsonFeed =
        "https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/Common/data/geojson/SamplePoiDataSet.json";

      function GetMap() {
        //Initialize a map instance.
        map = new atlas.Map("myMap", {
          center: [-73.929, 40.7406],
          zoom: 10,
          style: "grayscale_light",
          view: "Auto",

       
          authOptions: {
            authType: "subscriptionKey",
            subscriptionKey: "",
          },
        });

        //Wait until the map resources are ready.
        map.events.add("ready", function () {
          //Create a data source and add it to the map.
          datasource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
          map.sources.add(datasource);


          datasource.importDataFromUrl(geojsonFeed);

          //Create a layer to render the points.
          map.layers.add(
            new atlas.layer.BubbleLayer(datasource, null, {
              color: [
                "case",
                //If there is a color property, use it.
                ["has", "color"],
                ["get", "color"],

                //default to blue.
                "#3399ff",
              ],
            })
          );

          var control = new atlas.control.SelectionControl({
            style: "auto",
            //  selectionModes: ['circle', 'time']
            source: datasource,
          });

          map.events.add("dataselected", control, function (selectedShapes) {
            console.log(selectedShapes); // printing the selectedShapes 
            alert(selectedShapes.length + " shapes selected");
          });

          //Add controls to the map.
          map.controls.add(
            [
              //Optional. Add the map style control so we can see how the custom control reacts.
              new atlas.control.StyleControl({
                style: "auto",
                persistSearchArea: true,
              }),

              //Add the selection control to the map.
              control,
            ],
            {
              position: "top-left",
            }
          );
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="GetMap()">
    <div
      id="myMap"
      style="position: relative; width: 100%; min-width: 290px; height: 600px"
    ></div>

    <fieldset
      style="width: calc(100% - 30px); min-width: 290px; margin-top: 10px"
    >
      <legend><h1 style="font-size: 16px">Selection control</h1></legend>
      This sample shows how to use the selection control. This control connects
      to a data source and lets you draw polygon areas on the map and retrieve
      all the point shapes in the data source that are within that area. Press
      the pointer button in the top right corner of the map to choose a
      selection mode, then draw on the map. This samples uses the open source
      <a
        href="https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-maps-selection-control/"
        target="_blank"
        >Azure Maps Selection Control module</a
      >
    </fieldset>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm using the azure maps selection module to filter out a data points based on selection. But console.log (selectedShapes) on "dataselected" event returns a array with undefined values. However the alert shows the number of elements in the array. But they are all undefined. Is there anything that I'm missing ? Thanks.

Comment: I have created a pull request with a possible fix in the azure-maps-selection-control codebase. Let us see if the technical team accepts the fix.

Comment: Thanks for the pull request. I've merged the fix into the TypeScript code.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user resolve their own issue in the comments.